# Remove & Update Selected Row or Item from Datagrid In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I am trying to remove selected row of datagrid from database. 
I am able to save data in database but I don't know how to delete. I am using SQLITE Database.

**Note:** I am using DataGrid not datagridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void DeleteButtonClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.SelectedItem == null)
        return;
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem; // Assuming that you are having a DataTable.DefaultView as ItemsSource;

    DB.Execute("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE myCol=" + rowView["myCol"]); // rowView[ColumnName] retrieves the value for you, Use your Primary Column's name here;
}
```

This should help you :)

Comment: Declare DataRowView 'rowView'. That is what is returned by the datagrid-selecteditem ( DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem; ). By DB.Execute, I meant your method which handles SQLite operations.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a query using the `DELETE` statement. Something like

```
$"DELETE FROM table WHERE id = {row["id"]}"
```

Comment: Please tell me what is "row"

Comment: The row you're trying to delete. Assuming you're using a `DataTable` as `DataContext` it could be retrieved by using the `DataTable.RowDeleting` event